# Git base code to be shared to multiple branches

Tags: git, version-control

I have a code that is reused for multiple projects. I'm having hard time to maintain across all branches.

What's the strategy to maintain all of my branches? Say if I have a base code in one branch, how do I sync to all of my branches whenever I push to the base code?

The features is not always the same, but most of them will share the same features.

Comment: [Sharing your research helps everyone](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important). Tell us what you've tried and why it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Comment: Do not hesitate to provide examples that are representative to the issue you have in your question. I feel your description is a little bit too vague as it is.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a code that is reused for multiple projects. I'm having hard time to maintain across all branches.

It seems you are suggesting to have different projects in different branches of the same repository. **Don't**. This isn't how you're supposed to use Git.

> Say if I have a base code in one branch, how do I sync to all of my branches whenever I push to the base code?

Very basically, this isn't how you're supposed to use branches in a git repository. I don't conclusively know if it can be done - but I do know that it **shouldn't** be done.
Git merges should always happen with consent of the target branch owner. What you're asking for is to effectively push it onto the target branch automatically without any validation on whether the merge is wanted/warranted.

A much more appropriate approach is **packaging**. Depending on your environment there are different platforms (e.g. Nuget, npm). I'm going to refer to Nuget by way of example, but in reality any package platform fits the bill. Choose whichever platform is the most appropriate for your environment.

Take your shared logic and put it in a project of its own. Create a package out of this project and put it on a Nuget server.

Take all your projects (= branches) and give them their own git repository. If this project relies on the shared logic, add the Nuget package which you created in the previous step.

Should your shared logic change at any point, simply repackage it and put it online (use version numbering appropriately). Now, all of your other projects are able to fetch the updated version from the Nuget server.

Depending on how you configure your packages in your (consumer) project, these updated can be fetched automatically (always downloading the latest version) or manually (requiring the developer explicitly to choose to use the latest version). It depends on what is appropriate for you.